# Symfony: how to cache a FormInterface object

Tags: forms, symfony, caching

I have a form type in Symfony that shows in every page list and I'd like to catch it to avoid unnecessary database queries as it uses two EntityTypes fields:

```
->add('brand', EntityType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                'class' => Brand::class,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'query_builder' => function (BrandRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('b')
                        ->orderBy('b.name', 'ASC');
                },
            ])
            ->add('car_manufacturer', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => CarManufacturer::class,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'required' => false,
                'query_builder' => function (CarManufacturerRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('m')
                        ->orderBy('m.name', 'ASC');
                },
            ])
            ->add('Search', SubmitType::class);
```

So in the controller I tried to do this:

```
private function getFiltersForm(): FormInterface {

        $cachedForm = $this->cache
            ->getItem('form_list_filters')
            ->expiresAfter(3600*24);

        if (!$cachedForm->isHit()) {
            $form = $this->formFactory->createNamedBuilder('', SearchItemType::class)->getForm();
            $cachedForm->set($form);
            $this->cache->save($cachedForm);
        }
        return $cachedForm->get();
    }
```

But it doesn't work, the `isHit()`is always false and the form is always regenerated which makes me thing there must be some problem on the save process.

Any idea? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[Symfony caching requires the object to be serializable by PHP](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache/cache_items.html).

If you wrap your object in a try catch and attempt to serialize() it, you can test that out pretty easily.

```
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.serialization.php
```